# Bokeh Taptool return selected index

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I need to get the index of a selected data point in a Bokeh plot, which needs to be the input of another function in my web application.

I am using Bokeh's Taptool CustomJS Callback. However, I could not find a way to get the actual index of the selected point besides 'console.log'. Is there some way to return this index to outside the JavaScript?

Below is my code. I am new to Javascript and Bokeh. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
codes = """
    var index_selected = source.selected['1d']['indices'][0];
    source.trigger('change');

    console.log(index_selected);
    """
taptool.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source),code = codes)
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the index?  In general, once you reach the javascript interface of Bokeh, it is designed to stay there.  If you need to return a value back to Python, then you need to also be running a Bokeh from a server that is running Python.  Also, what version of Bokeh are you using?  `source.trigger('change')` is depricated, you should be using `source.change.emit()`.

Comment: Are you asking about getting the indices back to *Python*? If so, you will have to run a Bokeh server app. When you make standalone Bokeh output, it generates static HTML and JS code that is not connected to any Python process.

Comment: Well obviously you need to run a bokeh server if you want the answer in python but that doesn't provide any clue as to how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This works with multi_line:

```
selected_src = ColumnDataSource(dict(indices=[])

def handle_selection_change(_attr, # should be 'data'
                            old_indices, 
                            new_indices):
   ...

selected_src.on_change('data', handle_selection_change)

taptool.callback = CustomJS(
    args=dict(source=source, selected=selected_src),
    code = """
       selected.data = { "indices" : source.selected.indices };
    """)
```

Comment: Can't get this to work. Don't know what `handle_selection_change` is supposed to do (filled the function with `pass`), but `selected_src` seems alwawys to be empty.

Comment: `handle_selection_change` does whatever you need in response to changes of the line selections. In my code, I use the `new_indices['indices'I` to update another control based on the selected lines. I see that my code actually has something like `{"indices" : source.selected.indices  }`, so I might have written that down backward. See if that fixes it.

Comment: `{"indices" : source.selected.indices }` indeed fixed it.

Comment: I modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following example plots two triangles. By tapping on a triangle, the corresponding index gets printed. The example is not using CustomJS though.

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc

def my_tap_handler(attr,old,new):
    index = source.selected.indices
    print(index)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[[1,2,3],[7,8,8,]],
    y=[[2,1,3],[6,8,7]]
))
p = figure(tools="tap")

renderer = p.patches('x', 'y', source=source)
renderer.data_source.on_change("selected", my_tap_handler)
curdoc().add_root(p)
```

Comment: That might work for patches (I didn't try) but it does not appear to work with multi_line